# how to store multiple array of same name from one form

Tags: php, mysql

suppose i m trying to store name,phone email of three person from one form here is my code..

```
<form method="post" action="demo.php">
    <input type="text" name="name[]">
    <input type="text" name="phone[]">
    <input type="text" name="email[]">
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="name[]">
    <input type="text" name="phone[]">
    <input type="text" name="email[]">
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="name[]">
    <input type="text" name="phone[]">
    <input type="text" name="email[]">
    <br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

now code of demo.php which is my action  page...

```
foreach(($_POST['name']as $id)
    {
        $name= mysql_real_escape_string($id);

        $query1 = "INSERT INTO list (name,phone,email) VALUES ('$name','$_POST[phone]',$_POST[email])";
        $query = mysql_query($query1);
    }
    if($query)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else{
        echo "Something Wrong";
    }
```

its storing name of three  people correctly but not storing phone and email of three people
i tried with for loop also but not getting result,plz anyone tell me how to store multiple array from a single  form.

Comment: `$_POST['phone']` and `$_POST['email']` contain arrays. You probably want to pop() (or maybe unshift(), I haven't thought about it) those arrays. Also, you are writing code that is vulnerable to SQL injection. Please use a non-obsolete database library (such as PDO) and make use of prepared statements, so as to avoid introducing vulnerabilities into your application.

Comment: my question is very simple how to store multiple data of same name from a single form,if u have any working script then plz show me,thanks.

Comment: I will not write code for you, but I will tell you what you can do to make your code work. As I said, `$_POST['phone']` and `$_POST['email']` contain arrays. They respectively contain all of the entered phone numbers and all of the entered email addresses. PHP provides a number of functions for manipulating arrays. You want to use `.pop()` on each array at each iteration of the loop. Or it might be `.unshift()` rather than `.pop()`, as I said previously.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
// variables of the form
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

foreach($_POST['name']as $k => $id)
{
    $name= mysql_real_escape_string($id);

    $query1 = "INSERT INTO list (name,phone,email) VALUES ('$name','$phone[$k]','$email[$k]')";
    $query = mysql_query($query1);
}
if($query)
{
    return true;
}
else{
    echo "Something Wrong";
}
```

Comment: you made one mistake see here foreach(($_POST['name']as $k => $id) i used foreach($_POST['name']as $k => $id) and done.  thanks dear solved....u r really great..

Comment: Yes, you are right, I copied the code exactly as it was above, thanks!